# guidance needed for corda Application design

Tags: corda

I have a web background majorly with javascript, I have started learning Corda recently for project implementation and need guidance in this regard,
So our application is based on the web, the user signs up with different school name, create question papers, and then want to share either part of it or whole with teachers of some other school in our platform. they can make changes and assign it back to creator and the process goes back and forth, finally signing the paper to be finalized, once finalized it cannot be changed by anyone. I need to store these transactions in Corda application, not sure how to go about it, I did try replicating it using negotiation application in corda/kotlin/sample, but stuck in a bug as I was trying to send a list of objects.
I do have the following questions in mind

1. Should I use enterprise edition or go with open source as I think I need schema design for this. web db is in postgress
2. As far as I have seen each node is predefined in the config with username and password,is there a way to create the node while the user signs up.
3. I have schools and teachers inside the school, do I need a separate node for each school and then create states in each node(not sure if a node can be set up at run time). or do I use the account's library provided for creating the account of each teacher, if yes id there a way to use passwords in it, unable to find password field in it.
4. how do I send an array of objects to the state, or should I create a separate state for each question, as different questions can be assigned to different teachers, but again multiple questions can be assigned to the same teacher.

These are few questions on my mind any help is much appreciated, as most of the examples gave IOU samples or states with int and string, Please guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Hi, @Affan, I think the easiest way for you is to take a look to the cordapp samples on github (https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/) to take a look on what you can implement with Corda, and join the community on Slack (https://slack.corda.net/) to ask detailed questions, in case something is not clear.
In general, the application you describe does not seem to need a blockchain, but again I strongly invite you to check the samples.

Answer (score 0):

Alessandro has good advice here, definitely look at the samples repos for inspiration on how to build what you're looking for.

1. start with open source, it's easier to prototype and you can switch to enterprise later it won't be an issue for you
2. this depends on design, you wouldn't really want to create a new corda node per-person, you might want to have corda accounts that run on a single node instead. See accounts sdk here: https://github.com/corda/accounts
3. what you might do is make a corda node for each school and then accounts per teacher like you were already were thinking. That would mean only a couple of nodes based on the number of schools you have.
4. as long as your state is marked with @CordaSerializable you won't have problems sending arrays of data, I send an array in a state in this sample here: https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/master/Advanced/secretsanta-cordapp/contracts/src/main/java/net/corda/samples/secretsanta/states/SantaSessionState.java#L24

https://github.com/corda/samples-java

https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin